How can I fasten direct transfer process from one to another AWS S3 using boto3?
Trying to fasten the direct transfer process of files/objects from one AWS S3 object storage to another where both have different credential.
I tried to follow the code given on below link but its still not working and to transfer the 126 MB file as well its taking more than 30 seconds.
How can I increase my AWS s3 upload speed when using boto3?
Please assist if anything not correct or any other way need to opt.... Thanks!!
def raw_from_prod_to_nonprod():
    import boto3
    import boto3.s3.transfer as s3transfer
    import botocore

    import urllib3
    urllib3.disable_warnings()

    from io import BytesIO

    service = "s3"
    verify_bool = False
    endpoint_url_with_https = "https://xx-xxxx.xx.xxx.xx:1234"

    src_access_key = ""
    src_secret_key = ""
    src_bucket = ""
    src_initial_path = "upload/2024/2024-05-17/"

    dst_access_key = ""
    dst_secret_key = ""
    dst_bucket = ""
    dst_initial_path = "download/2024/2024-05-17/"

    # Set the desired multipart threshold value (50MB)
    mb = 1024 ** 2
    min_size_of_file_for_multipart_threshold = 50

    workers = 20
    botocore_config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=workers)

    transfer_config = s3transfer.TransferConfig(
        use_threads=True,
        max_concurrency=workers,
        multipart_threshold=min_size_of_file_for_multipart_threshold * mb
    )

    src = boto3.client(
        service_name=service,
        verify=verify_bool,
        endpoint_url=endpoint_url_with_https,
        aws_access_key_id=src_access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=src_secret_key,
        config=botocore_config
    )

    dst = boto3.client(
        service_name=service,
        verify=verify_bool,
        endpoint_url=endpoint_url_with_https,
        aws_access_key_id=dst_access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=dst_secret_key,
        config=botocore_config
    )  

    paginator = src.get_paginator('list_objects')
    response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
        Bucket=src_bucket,
        Prefix=src_initial_path,
        PaginationConfig={
            'PageSize': 1000,
            'MaxItems': 1000
        }
    )

    objs = response_iterator.build_full_result()['Contents']
    keys_to_copy = [o['Key'] for o in objs]  # or use a generator (o['Key'] for o in objs)

    s3t = s3transfer.create_transfer_manager(dst, transfer_config)

    for key in keys_to_copy:
        print(key)
        copy_source = {
            'Bucket': src_bucket,
            'Key': key
        }

        copy_to = {
            'Bucket': dst_bucket,
            'Key': dst_initial_path + key.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
       }

        src_response = src.get_object(Bucket=src_bucket, Key=key)
        src_data = src_response['Body'].read()
        future = s3t.upload(
            fileobj=BytesIO(src_data),
            bucket=dst_bucket,
            key=dst_initial_path + key.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
        )
        future.result()
        s3t.shutdown()  # wait for all the upload tasks to finish



raw_from_prod_to_nonprod()


What is "ECS object storage"? Are you using S3 object storage maybe? Your question seems to mix up ECS and S3 in such a way that it is really unclear what you are asking or what problem you are trying to solve.

If you are copying one S3 object, try using copy_object.

@MarkB .... Its for AWS S3 Compatible Storage. I mentioned ECS as that is the actual storage. Kindly have a look on code to assist how to fasten the direct transfer of files/objects from one AWS S3 object storage to another where both have different credential.

@jarmod .... I used that only however it looks like its not working with above mentioned code. Kindly have a look on code to assist how to fasten the direct transfer of files/objects from one AWS S3 object storage to another where both have different credential.

To copy an object using copy_object you need to supply the actual source and destination keys such as folder1/dog.png. You can't provide a prefix such as upload/2024/2024-05-17/.

ECS isn't "storage". I assume you are using ECS with an attached EBS volume or something? And I assume you are running something like MinIO on ECS? The software you are actually running (MinIO or whatever) should be included in your question. It honestly seems weird to me that if you are using AWS you would do that instead of just using S3, since you will get much lower fault-tolerance, and also have to pay much more for the compute services.

@jarmod .... Yes i am providing full keys not only prefix -> key=dst_initial_path + key.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

@MarkB really appreciate if by zoom or any other communication we can connect quickly to detail you please?

No, I'm not doing that. That's not how this site works, and people aren't going to get on video calls with you and help you with something like this for free. If you want to post a new question with all the details, like what actual "s3 compatible" software you are running on ECS, and what the backend storage is, etc. then I may attempt to provide more help.

@MarkB - There is no strict rule on by what medium anyone guides... but yes it always matters that how far we can go to support each other :)
In regards to your queue,

AWS S3 storage is there and
This code i am running from PyCharm not from any application
The transmission is happening using above code however its slow

And so posted this Q for guidance as not sure threading, max_concurrency etc. already in configuration in above code but still its not working.
Please have a look on code and advice where the problem is.... it will help a lot... Thanks!!

You aren't using S3 storage if the storage software is running on ECS. I'm sorry, but S3 itself does not run on ECS. You already said once you are using some sort of "S3 Compatible" software on ECS, which is not the same as actually using S3, it just has a compatible API. And yes you are wasting a ton of money on an inferior solution by using that on ECS instead of just using the actual AWS S3 service.
